# Cannot access method from included module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning ruby on rails 4, and want to use concern in ActiveSupport. Here's how I do it:

#### controllers/concerns/do_things_controller.rb

```
# file controllers/concerns/do_things_controller.rb
require 'active_support/concern'
module DoThings
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def do_something
    puts 'something'
  end

  included do
    helper_method :do_something
  end
end
```

#### controllers/application_controller.rb

```
# file controllers/application_controller.rb 
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  require 'concerns/do_things_controller'
  include DoThings
end
```

And in **views/layouts/application.html.haml** I call **do_something**, it shows error:

```
undefined method `do_something'
```

Thanks

Comment: I assume the `k` after your `require` argument in your `application_controller.rb` is a typo?

Comment: Can you show the code from your haml file?

Comment: Really weird, it words fine today!
I tried to add another method and got the problem again, restart Webrick then the error disappeared!
Is there any problem or rails requires to restart server every time I add new method to the module?

Also if I put method into ClassMethods module, there's no way to get it recognized.
Anyway, thanks alot @PeterAlfvin